# WPF Custom Textbox UserControl Extend .NetCore

Tags: c#, wpf, .net-core, binding, user-controls

I want to create my  text box user control in WPF.

```
 public partial class TadbirTextBox : TextBox, IDataErrorInfo 
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty ItemNameProperty =
      DependencyProperty.Register(
      "ItemName",
      typeof(string),
      typeof(TadbirTextBox),
      new FrameworkPropertyMetadata("", FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.BindsTwoWayByDefault)
      );

    public TadbirTextBox()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        
    }
    private TextBoxInputDataType _inputDataType = TextBoxInputDataType.GeneralType;
    public string ItemName
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue(ItemNameProperty); }
        set { SetValue(ItemNameProperty, value); }
    }
    public TextBoxInputDataType InputDataType
        {
            get { return _inputDataType; }
            set
            {_inputDataType = value;
        if (_inputDataType == TextBoxInputDataType.Email ||
            _inputDataType == TextBoxInputDataType.NationalCode ||
            _inputDataType == TextBoxInputDataType.Mobile ||
            _inputDataType == TextBoxInputDataType.PhoneNumber)
        {
            DataContext = this;
        }
 public string Error => throw new NotImplementedException();

        public string this[string columnName]
        {
   if (_inputDataType == TextBoxInputDataType.Email)
                {
                    Regex reg = new Regex(@"^[\w-\.]+@([\w-]+\.)+[\w-]{2,4}$");
                    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(Text) || !reg.IsMatch(Text))
                        return "Incorrect email format";
                }
       .......
```

and in xaml  :

```
<TextBox x:Class="TadbirDesktopWPF.Controles.TadbirTextBox"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             mc:Ignorable="d"  Text="{Binding ItemName, ValidatesOnDataErrors=True}" >

</TextBox>
```

I create an Enum represent type of textbox input :

```
 public enum TextBoxInputDataType
    {
        GeneralType,
        IntType,
        CurrencyType,
        DecimalType,
        Email,
        PhoneNumber,
        Mobile,
        NationalCode,
        PostalCode,
        EconomicCode
    }
```

and use it in my code like this :

```
<Controles:TadbirTextBox InputDataType="PhoneNumber"/>


 <Controles:TadbirTextBox  InputDataType="Email"/>
```

my problem is I can not add ValidationRole for each of InputDataType or access to Binding or change the StringFormat dynamically inside my UserControl code . have any idea ?
I need to add dynamically StringFormat to Bindig of this control from code behind or ...

Comment: What do you mean you can't? Whate have you tried that doesn't work?

Comment: add binding to TadbirTextBox . I need Binding to Add ValidationRole or StringFormat .If I want CurrencyType, need Stringformat for dynamically formating text with thousand separator and ...

Comment: @JavadAzimi: If you want to be able to bind to `InputDataType`, you should define it as a dependency property.

Comment: no it's work fine right now . but I want to format text value of textbox just as user entered.so I need to add dynamically StringFormat to Bindig of this control from code behind